# BootstrapTable not displaying checkbox column on reload from Ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatable, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-table

I am using a BootstrapTable with a checkbox in the first column. It works fine on initial load when I render it from the MVC view, but when I try to reload the data from AJAX it's not displaying checkbox column. I'm not sure why it's not working.

It's working fine in my local environment but gives me the issue on the client's production server.

```js
$.ajax({
  url: '/ShippingMonitor/GetShippingData',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: JSON.stringify(data),
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  success: function(data) {
    // console.log(data);
    if (data.ResultCode == "200") {
      $('#table').bootstrapTable('load', data.Response);
    }
  },
  error: function(err) {
    $("#table tbody").html('');
  },
  beforeSend: function() {
    $("#table tbody").html($(".dataLoading").html());
  }
});
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the console when you view the site on the production server?

Comment: Nope. There was an error of the fonts not loading but I resolved those. Except that no errors